# iAd appears on simulator but not on device

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, iad

When I run my application I can see my iAd in the simulator, that is pre-filled with "Test Advertisement"

However, when I run the application on my device, the iAd area is blank, with no pre-filled ad.

Why is this?

I am from India...Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK iAds are only available in US currently so that might be the problem.